# Customize new tab page in Firefox

Tags: windows-7, firefox

I am trying to customize the tab groups in the new version of Firefox. Is it possible to customize the new tab page in Firefox so that each tab group has its own pages or thumbnails?

**Edit:** I use Firefox 20, Windows 7.

When I open a new tab, a page opens with thumbnails to the most frequently used websites. I want to customize this page so that when I open it from different tab groups, I get different thumbnails. In other words, I want to set the default thumbnails for each tab group.

Comment: Please include your firefox version, the operating system you are using and a more detailed explanation of what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Super Start](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/super-start/?src=amo-similar-addons)

It has exactly what you want.